# Load an assembly and copy it with different name and extension

Tags: c#, assemblies, reflection.emit, system.reflection

Recently I started to use Reflection, Reflection.Emit and Code Dom. The purpose of my coding is to load an assembly (e.g. "C:\Temp\MyAssembly.exe"), read its classes and methods. This has been done however I am interested to save a copy of "MyAssembly.exe" to "MyAssembly.dll". The reason is because I want to instrument the code and make some changes to the methods. 
I am aware about how to create new assemblies and save them, but I am not sure if it is possible to "clone" an existing assembly (including all its classes and methods)  with extension .exe to .dll.

I will appreciate any advice!
Thanks.
Peter

Comment: Why does it have to be a DLL? There is very little difference between DLL and EXE files in .Net.

Comment: Hi svick, I need it as dll because later on I will use a tool called PeX --Program Exploration-- (from command line) to explore some methods. Thanks for your interest!

Comment: And are you sure PeX doesn't work with exe files?

Comment: Yes, it can run both .exe and .dll, however how could make a copy or "clone" of the assembly using Reflection.Emit?

Comment: I still don't understand why do you want to make that copy. If you really want to do that, copying MyAssembly.exe to MyAssembly.dll should work.

Comment: Basically I needed to do the copy because I need to instrument the classes and methods inside of it without modifying the original assembly(.exe). I know that is not relevant to change the extention from .exe to .dll because of the reasons that you commented, I agree on that, but I wanted to change it just to follow certain rules. However it works the way that you told me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply saving a copy of "MyAssembly.exe" to "MyAssembly.dll" shouldn't be much of a problem (use File.Copy, for example) and doesn't require Reflection or Reflection.Emit.

But, as the comments reveal, the problem is more one of saving a *modified* copy of "MyAssembly.exe" to a different file name. It is not possible to modify an existing assembly using Reflection.Emit, but you have other options:

- you could use a third-party tool such as [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) or [Microsoft CCI](http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/) to load the assembly, modify it, and save it under a different name;
- you could use the IL disassembler and IL assembler included with the .NET framework/SDK to disassemble, then modify, then reassemble your assembly;
- in theory, you could probably load the assembly, analyze it via Reflection and emit a completely equivalent new assembly using Reflection.Emit; however, I'd not take that route, as it would be an enormous piece of work to get this right.